# AS3 - Drag using If statement to Next Scene.

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement, drag-and-drop

I am making an interactive game - and I have this code so far. Where drop1 is a coin and the user drops it into target1 (box) and once they have done they they are able to watch the video play in the next scene. AS you can see when drop1 (coin) is dropped onto the box the coin then disappears

```
  //Array to hold the target instances, the drop instances,   
  //and the start positions of the drop instances.
  var hitArray:Array = new Array(hitTarget1);
  var dropArray:Array = new Array(drop1);
  var positionsArray:Array = new Array();


  //This adds the mouse down and up listener to the drop instances
  //and add the starting x and y positions of the drop instances
  //into the array.
  for (var i:int = 0; i < dropArray.length; i++) {
  dropArray[i].buttonMode = true;
  dropArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mdown);
  dropArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mUp);

  positionsArray.push({xPos:dropArray[i].x, yPos:dropArray[i].y});
  }

  //This drags the object that has been selected and moves it
  //to the top of the display list. This means you can't drag
  //this object underneath anything.
  function mdown(e:MouseEvent):void {
  e.currentTarget.startDrag();
  setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);
  }

  //This stops the dragging of the selected object when the mouse is
  //released. If the object is dropped on the corresponding target
  //then it get set to the x and y position of the target. Otherwise
  //it returns to the original position.
  function mUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
  var dropIndex:int = dropArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
  var target:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

  target.stopDrag();

  if (target.hitTestObject(hitArray[dropIndex])) {
  target.x = hitArray[dropIndex].x;
  target.y = hitArray[dropIndex].y;
  drop1.visible = false;
  }else{
  target.x = positionsArray[dropIndex].xPos;
  target.y = positionsArray[dropIndex].yPos;

  }
  }
```

NOW... I want the code to know when the user has dropped the coin in the box and IF the user has they can then watch the video but can only watch the video if they drop the coin in box. How can i code this?

please help.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're still struggling you can always try reading the MANUAL..? I suspect this is why you've had no answer so far. Travelling between frames/scenes requires either gotoAndPlay or gotoAndStop. Check: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay()

Look at example two for scene jumping code. Where it says "intro" (frame label) it's okay to just use a number but scenes must have names.. e.g:

```
mc1.gotoAndPlay("intro", "Scene 12");
```

or in your case something like below (assuming you have named it as scene_video)

```
if (target.hitTestObject(hitArray[dropIndex])) {
target.x = hitArray[dropIndex].x;
target.y = hitArray[dropIndex].y;
drop1.visible = false;
gotoAndStop(1, "scene_video");     }
```

Again I'm assuming your video player is on frame 1 of that scene so stopping there allows users a chance to watch the video player.